# Php database connection security check

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I'm creating **Database connection** with following php code:

```
<?php 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'evantechbd');

$db = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER); 
if (!$db)
{
die('Could not connect to Server: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db("evantechbd",$db))
{
die('Could not connect to DataBase : ' . mysql_error());
} 
?>
```

Is it really secure ?

Comment: Is there some specific reason you're worried this *isn't* secure? Also, the `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated.

Comment: What is latest function?

Comment: [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) is a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure against what?

If you want it to secure against "rough module", it's not. All defined values will be accessible anywhere in included file (you should use config and unset it unset initialization).

```
$config = parse_ini_file( 'configs/config.php');
mysqli_connect( isset( $config['host']) ? $config['host'] : 'localhost',
    isset( $config['user']) ? $config['user'] : 'root', ...);
// Select DB
unset( $config);
// Prohibit your modules from opening any file
```

Against webuser? Again no. You're displaying error to end user. You're telling anyone that you're connection to `localhost` with user `root` if connection fails for any reason (you should use throw an exception, trigger error and notify user just about database error, send mail to yourself and log the error).

And using `root` without password is quite a big security issue, but I'm assuming that's just example data.

Comment: +1. Also, using the root user in production code isn't a good idea either. A specific user should be created for each application on the server, so if the database information should get compromised, only one site would be affected.

Comment: can you please give an example?

Comment: @KristianAntonsen yeah, you're right. We allow connection only from localhost on our mysql servers which makes great deal in security, but there are still applications (such as phpMyAdmin) which can be abused. I prefer naming users like `web_ae79ec` (with random hash as suffix) and long (about 8-20 characters) password.

Comment: example about your first suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The biggest security issue is that your `root` database user really should have a password.

Comment: Well, i'm just test it on my localhost server. when i upload it to server i must be change this. But is it secure?

Comment: Define "secure". What are you trying to protect against? Other parts of your code are more likely to be an issue.

Comment: protect to hacking.. What is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that this code does essentially nothing by itself. There's not really any avenue for a web user to attack here, but when dealing with SQL, there are plenty of things to protect against, like SQL injection.

Comment: Well... So how do i prevent sql injection?

Comment: None of this code is vulnerable to SQL injection, as you aren't actually **doing** anything with SQL other than connecting in this code. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection